Set column names
I am bringing in the data from an Excel spreadsheet.
I want to make all the info from df.row(8) into the column header names.
In pandas it was just:
c = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' ]
df.columns = c

Using the rename does not seem very practical here. Is there an easier way?

In general, assigning to df.columns is supported in polars as well.

it apprears to be two issues.  the df.row(8) from excel is a tuple. Then all the blank Excel data show up as just None.  Not "None".  And there were multiple None names so not unique.   will try to drop th Null columns first.  convert tuple to list format.  i think that should work?  thanks for your help - i would have spent all night trying to figure out???

@diogenes would be easier to help you if you had a reproduceable example. You can also skip empty rows - see my answer

You can rename your columns by assigning df.columns in polars, and you can use pl.DataFrame.row() to get row by index:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a":list("cdf"),
    "b":list("abc")
})

df.columns = df.row(2)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ f   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ c   ┆ a   │
│ d   ┆ b   │
│ f   ┆ c   │
└─────┴─────┘

Alternatively, if you have no meaningful rows before row 8, it should by default put values from this row into column names (due to drop_empty_rows and has_header parameters being True by default), although the row itself is not going to be present in the data.
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a":[None]*3 + list("cdf"),
    "b":[None]*3 + list("abc")
})

# shape: (6, 2)
# ┌──────┬──────┐
# │ a    ┆ b    │
# │ ---  ┆ ---  │
# │ str  ┆ str  │
# ╞══════╪══════╡
# │ null ┆ null │
# │ null ┆ null │
# │ null ┆ null │
# │ c    ┆ a    │
# │ d    ┆ b    │
# │ f    ┆ c    │
# └──────┴──────┘

df.write_excel("test.xlsx", include_header=False)
pl.read_excel("test.xlsx")

shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ c   ┆ a   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ d   ┆ b   │
│ f   ┆ c   │
└─────┴─────┘

update if you want to rename only some columns and skip None values, you could use pl.DataFrame.to_dicts() and pl.DataFrame.rename():
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a":["new_a","c","d"],
    "b":[None,"g","h"]
})

# shape: (3, 2)
# ┌───────┬──────┐
# │ a     ┆ b    │
# │ ---   ┆ ---  │
# │ str   ┆ str  │
# ╞═══════╪══════╡
# │ new_a ┆ null │
# │ c     ┆ g    │
# │ d     ┆ h    │
# └───────┴──────┘

N = 0
d = df.slice(N, 1).to_dicts()[0]      # take row at index N and convert it to dict
d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if v}   # remove None values from dict

df.rename(d)

shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬──────┐
│ new_a ┆ b    │
│ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ str   ┆ str  │
╞═══════╪══════╡
│ new_a ┆ null │
│ c     ┆ g    │
│ d     ┆ h    │
└───────┴──────┘

